# Ошибка в написании программы на Питоне

Tags: python

Дана точка на плоскости с координатами (x,y). Составить программу, которая выдает одно из сообщений "Да", "Нет", "На границе" в зависимости от того, лежит ли точка внутри заштрихованной области, вне области или на ее границе.

```
y,x= int(inpyt())
if ((x==0)or(x==10))and((y==0)or(y==5))
    print("точка лежит на границе")
elif if ((x>0)and(x<10)and(y>0)and(y<5))
    print("точка принадлежит")
else
    print("точка принадлежит")
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Answer (score 4):

1. Вы забыли двоеточия в строчках с `if`, `elif` и `else`.
2. После `elif` уже не нужно ещё одно `if`.
3. Ошибка в написании слова `input`.
4. В первой строчке вы пытаетесь из введённой пользователем строки сначала получить одно число, а потом запихнуть его в две переменные. Это работать не будет. Сделайте так:

   ```
   x, y = int(input()), int(input())
   ```

Comment: 5. скобки для `if` не нужны: `if (x == 'a'):` -> `if x == 'a':`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (0 < x < 10) and (0 < y < 5):
    print('yes')
elif ((x in (0, 10)) and (y in range(6))) or ((x in range(11)) and (y in (0, 5))):
    print('on border')
else:
    print('no')
```

Comment: `x in range(11)` и `y in range(6)` сработает, только если x и y - целые. Про это в условии задачи нигде не сказано, поэтому лучше все-таки сделать через условия больше-меньше.

Comment: @insolor, в коде автора x и y получаются в результате выполнения int(). Они просто не могут быть нецелыми.

Comment: спасибо большое, все исправила.